# how to change image of shape (885, 1268) to (1,254,254,3) in python?

Tags: python, opencv

how to change the image of shape  (885, 1268) to (1,254,254,3) in python?

I have an image from base64 which I converted to NumPy array and it is the shape of (885, 1268) so how to convert it to (1,254,254,3)

Comment: Isn't that a very different number of values?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode so is is possible or not

Comment: You tell us. It's not clear what you want. I've never even seen a 4D image.

Comment: i want to feed the image to a model. let's make it (254,254,3) its also oky

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your array if that's what you want. Make sure your dimensions add up.
For example, you can reshape (885, 1268) into (5, 177, 317, 4).

Comment: More like "multiply up" :-)